# views in thymeleaf spring boot templates sub folder

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf in spring boot, and have several views. I don't want to keep all the views in the same folder which is src/main/resources/templates by default.

Is it possible to move some of the view in src/main/resources/templates/folder1, and I will pass "folder1/*viewname*" to access that page?

When I tried http://localhost:8080/folder1/layout1 it didn't found my html in src/main/resources/templates/folder1/, but when I move the html in templates main folder src/main/resources/templates/, http://localhost:8080/layout1 worked fine.

My controller class looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{pagename}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String mf42_layout1(@PathVariable String pagename) {
    return pagename;
}
```

So, I thought if I pass layout1, it will look int the templates, and if I say "a/layout1", it will look in /layout folder

Thanks,
Manish

Comment: have you tried it?

Comment: yes, but didn't worked. I have added it in the question now.

Comment: Short answer is: yes you can but that will depend on your spring-boot application set up. I have something like this in configured in spring-mvc. You probably need look around configuring view resolver in your spring-boot app. Adding more details to your question would definitely help.

Comment: what does your controller-method look like? please add more code.

Comment: just added the controller code

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Basically, your request mapping and the name of your view are decoupled, you just need to pay attention to the syntax.

For instance, with

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foobar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String mf42_layout1() {
    return "layout1";
}
```

a request to `http://localhost:8080/foobar` will render the template located in `src/main/resources/templates/layout1.html`.

It also works if you put your templates on a subfolder, as long as you provide the correct path to the view:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foobar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String mf42_layout1() {
    return "a/layout1";
}
```

A request to `http://localhost:8080/foobar` will render the template located in `src/main/resources/templates/a/layout1.html`.

You can also parameterized the url endpoint with @PathVariable:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foobar/{layout}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String mf42_layout1(@PathVariable(value = "layout") String layout) { // I prefer binding to the variable name explicitely
        return "a/" + layout;
    }
```

Now a request to `http://localhost:8080/foobar/layout1` will render the template in `src/main/resources/templates/a/layout1.html` and a request to `http://localhost:8080/foobar/layout2` will render what's in `src/main/resources/templates/a/layout2.html`

But beware the forward slash acts as a separator in URLs, so with your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{pagename}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String mf42_layout1(@PathVariable String pagename) {
    return pagename;
}
```

My guess is when you hit `http://localhost:8080/a/layout1` pagename receives "a" and "layout1" is not caught. So the controller probably tries to render the contents of `src/main/resources/templates/a.html`

The [Spring MVC reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping) extensively describes how to map requests, you should read it carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar template not found issue when running the application in a Linux server. I was using the path as "return "/a/layout1". This worked fine in a local windows PC, but I had to remove the starting "/" to make it work in a Linux box(i.e. "return "a/layout1").